# How to eliminate 1 second delay in DirectShow filter chain? (Using Delphi and DSPACK)

Tags: delphi, audio, directshow, dspack

I have a Delphi 6 Pro app that uses the DSPACK component library to send audio to Skype from the system's preferred audio input device.  I am using a TSampleGrabber component to tap into the Filter Graph chain and then send the audio buffers to Skype.  The problem is that I am only getting audio once a second.  In other words, the OnBuffer() event for the TSampleGrabber instance only fires once a second with a full second's worth of data in the Buffer parameter.  I need to know how to modify my Filter Graph chain so it grabs data from the input device at a faster interval than once a second.  If possible, I'd like to do it as fast as every 50 ms or at least every 100ms.

My Filter Graph chain consists of a TFilter that is mapped to the system's preferred audio input device at the top.  I attach the output pins of that filter to the input pins of a 'WAV Dest' assigned TFilter so I can get the samples in PCM WAV format.  I then attach the output pins of the 'WAV Dest' filter to the input pins of the TSampleGrabber instance.  What do I need to change to get the TSampleGrabber OnBuffer() event to fire at a faster interval?

---

**UPDATE**: Based on Roman R's answer I was able to implement a solution that I am showing below.  One note.  His link led me to the following blog post that was helpful in solution:

http://sid6581.wordpress.com/2006/10/09/minimizing-audio-capture-latency-in-directshow/

```
// Variable declaration for output pin to manipulate.
var
    intfCapturePin: IPin;

...............


    // Put this code after you have initialized your audio capture device
    //  TFilter instance *and* set it's wave audio format.  My variable for
    //  this is FFiltAudCap.  I believe you need to set the buffer size before
    //  connecting up the pins of the Filters.  The media type was
    //  retrieved earlier (theMediaType) when I initialized the audio
    //  input device Filter so you will need to do similarly.

    // Get a reference to the desired output pin for the audio capture device.
    with FFiltAudCap as IBaseFilter do
        CheckDSError(findPin(StringToOleStr('Capture'), intfCapturePin));

    if not Assigned(intfCapturePin) then
        raise Exception.Create('Unable to find the audio input device''s Capture output pin.');

    // Set the capture device buffer to 50 ms worth of audio data to
    //  reduce latency.  NOTE: This will fail if the device does not
    //  support the latency you desire so make sure you watch out for that.
    setBufferLatency(intfCapturePin as IAMBufferNegotiation, 50, theMediaType);

..................

// The setBufferLatency() procedure.
procedure setBufferLatency(
                // A buffer negotiation interface pointer.
                intfBufNegotiate: IAMBufferNegotiation;
                // The desired latency in milliseconds.
                bufLatencyMS: WORD;
                // The media type the audio stream is set to.
                theMediaType: TMediaType);
var
    allocProp: _AllocatorProperties;
    wfex: TWaveFormatEx;
begin
    if not Assigned(intfBufNegotiate) then
        raise Exception.Create('The buffer negotiation interface object is unassigned.');

    // Calculate the number of bytes per second using the wave
    // format belonging to the given Media Type.
    wfex := getWaveFormat(theMediaType);

    if wfex.nAvgBytesPerSec = 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('The average bytes per second value for the given Media Type is 0.');

    allocProp.cbAlign := -1;  // -1 means "no preference".
    // Calculate the size of the buffer needed to get the desired
    //  latency in milliseconds given the average bytes per second
    //  of the Media Type's audio format.
    allocProp.cbBuffer := Trunc(wfex.nAvgBytesPerSec * (bufLatencyMS / 1000));
    allocProp.cbPrefix := -1;
    allocProp.cBuffers := -1;

    // Try to set the buffer size to the desired.
    CheckDSError(intfBufNegotiate.SuggestAllocatorProperties(allocProp));
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you need to fine tune Audio Capture filter to capture in buffers of the size you want, i.e. short enough to make overall latency small.

Audio capture filters expose `IAMBufferNegotiation` interface on output pins and `SuggestAllocatorProperties` lets you specify buffer configuration.

See for more info: [Configuring Windows Media Audio Encoder DMO to reduce delay](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/9257bab3-383a-4e8c-8da6-7d9548f09716/).

Comment: Thanks @Roman R.  I have updated my original post to include a solution that I found following your original link.